# Wrapping up cfiles and related dependences to implement them in C++/Windows?

Tags: c++, c, linux, cmake, i2c

I have an assignment to write a program to implement i2c communication between a temp sensor and the Adafruit FT232H Breakout board (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-ft232h-breakout/overview).

The end result is this running on a Linux computer, and they did not want it implemented in python like the examples, so I decided on using the suggested C library, libmpsse,(https://code.google.com/p/libmpsse/).

after installing the libftdi library that it needs, as well as the libpmpsse code. I was able to get the .c code working, using the make provided.

There Make

```
LDFLAGS= -lmpsse

all: spiflash spiflashfast i2ceeprom ds1305 gpio bitbang

spiflash:

spiflashfast: 

i2ceeprom :
           $(CC) $(CFlags) i2ceeprom.c -o i2ceeprom $(LDFLAGS)

ds1305:

clean:
           rm -f* .dsym
           rm -f spiflash spiflashfast i2ceeprom ds1305 gpio bitbang

distclean: clean
```

What I am hoping to be able to do, is take all the required library's and wrap it all together in one package (cmake?) With the end result being single functions in a c++ file that will be able to run the functions in my .c code.

What I've tried:
Using CMake, I tried to use the add_libraycommand to tie the lmpsse.c together.
I cant post any more links but it looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(i2c)

add_library(i2cFunctions, lmpsse.c)
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/i2cFunctions")
add_subdirectory(i2cFunctions)

add_executable(i2c i2ceeprom.c)
target_link_libraries(i2c i2cFunctions)
```

I then run it, with the files I want in the dir above, but it produces

```
Linking C executable i2c
CMakeFiles/i2c.dir/i2ceeprom.c.o: In function `main':
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `MPSSE'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xa0): undefined reference to `Start'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xb6): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xcc): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xd8): undefined reference to `GetAck'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `Stop'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `Start'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x10e): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x11a): undefined reference to `GetAck'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x133): undefined reference to `Read'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x15b): undefined reference to `Stop'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x18c): undefined reference to `Start'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1a2): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1c4): undefined reference to `Stop'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `Start'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1e6): undefined reference to `Write'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x1f2): undefined reference to `SendAcks'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `Read'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x213): undefined reference to `SendNacks'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x224): undefined reference to `Read'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x234): undefined reference to `Stop'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `Stop'
i2ceeprom.c:(.text+0x716): undefined reference to `ErrorString'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [i2c] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/i2c.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks for any ideas or help you might have, 
If my explanation is a little weird I would be happy to explain better.

Comment: C++ mangles function names.  So the header files for your C functions need to have something like: `#ifdef _cpluscplus extern "C" { #endif ..... #ifdef _cpluscplus } #endif`  where the '....' is the prototypes for the C functions that you want the C++ program to call